# Ajax call in wordpress returns -1 & no code is run from the functions.php file

Tags: wordpress, jquery, wordpress-theming

I have to insert values into database table wp_ratings table using ajax in wordpress but it is not working. Below is the code i am using:

Ajax call:

```
$(function(){
            $('#submit').click(function(){
            var rating_allowed=document.getElementById("rating_allowed").value;
            var product_id=document.getElementById("product_id").value;
            var user_id=document.getElementById("user_id").value;
            var pc_ip=document.getElementById("pc_ip").value;
            var performance_input=document.getElementById("performance_input").value;
            var features_input=document.getElementById("features_input").value;
            var battery_input=document.getElementById("battery_input").value;
            var overall_input=document.getElementById("overall_input").value;
            var rating_cat_count=document.getElementById("rating_cat_count").value;
            var rate_1_name_find=document.getElementById("rate_1_name_find").value;
            var rate_2_name_find=document.getElementById("rate_2_name_find").value;
            var rate_3_name_find=document.getElementById("rate_3_name_find").value;
            var rate_4_name_find=document.getElementById("rate_4_name_find").value;
            var pros=document.getElementById("pros").value;
            var cons=document.getElementById("cons").value;
            alert("g");
            alert("action=updateRating&product_id=" + product_id + "&user_id=" + user_id + "&pc_ip=" + pc_ip + "&performance_input=" + performance_input + "&features_input=" + features_input + "&battery_input=" + battery_input + "&overall_input=" + overall_input + "&rating_cat_count=" + rating_cat_count +"&rate_1_name_find=" + rate_1_name_find + "&rate_2_name_find=" + rate_2_name_find + "&rate_3_name_find=" + rate_3_name_find + "&rate_4_name_find=" + rate_4_name_find + "&pros=" + pros + "&cons=" + cons);
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                            type:'POST',
                                                        data:"action=updateRating&product_id=" + product_id + "&user_id=" + user_id + "&pc_ip=" + pc_ip + "&performance_input=" + performance_input + "&features_input=" + features_input + "&battery_input=" + battery_input + "&overall_input=" + overall_input + "&rating_cat_count=" + rating_cat_count +"&rate_1_name_find=" + rate_1_name_find + "&rate_2_name_find=" + rate_2_name_find + "&rate_3_name_find=" + rate_3_name_find + "&rate_4_name_find=" + rate_4_name_find + "&pros=" + pros + "&cons=" + cons,
                             success:function(results)
                                 {
                                  alert(results);

                                        }
                                   });
                          }
                                    );
});
```

in functions.php file:

```
function implement_ajax_updateRating() 
{


        $p_id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['product_id'])));

        $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['user_id'])));

        $pc_ip = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['pc_ip'])));

        $rate_1 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['performance_input'])));

        $rate_2 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['features_input'])));

        $rate_3 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['battery_input'])));

        $rate_4 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['overall_input'])));

        $rating_cat_numbers = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['rating_cat_count'])));

        $rate_1_find = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['rate_1_name_find'])));

        $rate_2_find = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['rate_2_name_find'])));

        $rate_3_find = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['rate_3_name_find'])));

        $rate_4_find = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['rate_4_name_find'])));

        $pros = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['pros'])));

        $cons = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['cons'])));


        //add_post_meta('17', 'ff_value', "ff", true); 


        $rating_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_rating (post_id, rating_1, rating_2,rating_3,rating_4,user_id,comment_id,pc_ip,pros,cons)

        VALUES (".$p_id.", ".$rate_1.", ".$rate_2.",".$rate_3.",".$rate_4.",".$user_id.",".$comment_id.",'".$pc_ip."','".$pros."','".$cons."')");

        //$multi_in = multiRatingWidth($p_id, $rating_cat_numbers, $rate_1_find, $rate_2_find, $rate_3_find, $rate_4_find);

die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_updateRating', 'implement_ajax_updateRating');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateRating', 'implement_ajax_updateRating');
```

But alert is returning -1 & nothing is saved in database.

Comment: Could you post the URL output in the alert box above please? e.g. action=updateRating&product_id=...

Comment: action=updateRating&product_id=17&user_id=1&pc_ip=124.253.93.243&performance_input=3&features_input=3&battery_input=5&overall_input=0&rating_cat_count=3&rate_1_name_find=1&rate_2_name_find=1&rate_3_name_find=1&rate_4_name_find=0&pros=df&cons=f

Comment: You may need to spool out your $_POST collection in the PHP file. ps: Don't use GetElementByID if you're using jQuery :) Use a selector instead!